# Solr Index and Querying text with - in it

Tags: solr

new to Solr, have got it running and have imported some sample data, having problems with configuring the schema to work the way it needs to work. 
ALl i really want to do is index a string field, and be able to search it using begins with. So for example if field A has recrods with Car 1, Carrot, Car-3, Castle, Cars, Car2, Car3 etc then when i enter car i would expect all to be returned order by those with "car" first (full word car matching most (eg: car 1 before carrot and cars) (and then those with numbers/dashes), basically alpha numeric sorting.

How would i configure such a fileds index/analyser properties to achieve this?
With my current config i can search but the results are not returned alhanumeric and i cant search for the symbol "-".

The field should handle value that has space and dash in it like the example above.

this is my current config for that field based on some info i gogoled:

```
<!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- A text type for English text where stopwords and synonyms are managed using the REST API -->
    <fieldType name="managed_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="english" />
        <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymFilterFactory" managed="english" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

The results are by default returned by score, which is computed using a range of different factors. If you want a simple alphanumeric sort instead, add `&sort=sort_fieldname` to your query.

Be aware, you do not want to sort by a TextField (`text_ws` and `managed_en` in your example are TextFields) that generate multiple tokens (so the `WhitespaceTokenizer` and `StandardTokenizer` are out of the picture for a sort field, use `KeywordTokenizer` instead if you need analyzers or filters in the chain). If you don't need to do anything with the field (such as lowercasing it, etc.), use a `StrField` instead, as it's stored verbatim.

I'm guessing the next question would be "but .. do I need to submit the data twice then?", so no, use `copyField` in your schema to send the value that goes into `text_ws` to `sort_fieldname` was well, and apply a different type / analyzer chain for that field. In Lucene (and by extension Solr), you add fields with different chains to solve specific issues. Sorting is one such problem that's useful to do different from the actual search.